# how to read int values from a file.txt using fread() function in C?

Tags: c, file, fread

I would like to read some int values from a file which contains :

```
1
821
4
5423
2
```

I used this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
int main() {
  int buffer[N]; // Buffer to store data
  int i ;
  FILE * stream;
  stream = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  fread(&buffer, sizeof(int), N, stream);
  fclose(stream);
  // Printing data to check validity
    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
    printf("buffer[%d] : %d \n",i,buffer[i]);
    printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

but what I obtain are some random values and not file values

```
buffer[0] : 842533425 
buffer[1] : 171182641 
buffer[2] : 858928181 
buffer[3] : 168440330 
buffer[4] : 2106524480
```

Comment: use [fscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) to read the formatted data instead of [fwrite](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) which reads in bytes

Comment: The simple answer is that you don't use binary-file functions to read text.

Comment: I know how to do it with the `fscanf()` but I want to use the 'fread()' because it has less complexity time

Comment: In that case, do it in a similar way you would with `getchar()`. For each input digit `num = num * 10 + digit`. But if you want less time complexity that `scanf()` you can use `fgets()` and `atoi()` or `strtol()`.

Comment: Since your file has multiple lines, consider saving them into a **char** buffer and then use **sscanf** to get whatever values you wish.

Comment: If you want to use `fread`, you still need to convert the data to integers.  The string `12345` is not an integer, and if you want to convert those 5 bytes of data into a 4 byte integer, you will probably need to read them into an array of size 6 and use `strtol` to compute the integer.  Or just use `fgetc` and the common hack of `a = 10* a + c - '0'` or similar.